# Enter, update and exit selections in a treemap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 v5 treemap that I show three levels of the hierarchy via a filter.  Showing all levels at once would make the map too busy.  I'd like to employ a drill down or drill up feature such that when you click on a given rect (either child or parent) that re-sets that rect as the root node and then displays another three levels of the hierarchy from that new root node.

I think I'm getting the new root node data, but I can't seem to get the map to update correctly with the `onclick` (the console.log in the `exit().remove()` doesn't get called after the onclick).  It seems like elements are not exiting correctly, or not getting to the `exit().remove()`.

Here is the code:

```
const treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([1200, 700])
  .paddingOuter(16);

d3.json("test.json").then(function(data) {

  // update the view
  const update = (d) => {
  //console.log(d)

  let rootNode = d3.hierarchy(d)

  console.log(rootNode)

  rootNode
    .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value; });

  treemapLayout(rootNode);


  let nodes = d3.select('svg g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(rootNode.descendants())

  nodes
    .enter()
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d.depth < 3;
    })
    .append('g')
    .merge(nodes)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'})



  //nodes
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
    .attr('style', function(d) {
      return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
    })
    .on('click', function(d.parent) { console.log(d.data.name); update(d); })

  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 4)
    .attr('dy', 14)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    })


  nodes
    .attr('style', function(d) { console.log('here'); return d; })
    .exit().remove()
  };

  update(data);
});
```

Here is the data in a simplified format:

```
{
  "name": "A1",
  "health": 0.521,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "health": 0.521,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "health": 0.614,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D1",
              "health": 0.666,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
                  "value": 30,
                  "health": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
                  "value": 35,
                  "health": 0.5
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D1-E3",
                  "value": 20,
                  "health": 0.7
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D2",
              "health": 0.45,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                  "value": 10,
                  "health": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                  "value": 14,
                  "health": 0.1
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D3",
              "health": 0.64,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E1",
                  "value": 10,
                  "health": 0.8
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E2",
                  "value": 14,
                  "health": 0.2
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E3",
                  "value": 7,
                  "health": 0.7
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E4",
                  "value": 9,
                  "health": 0.9
                },
                {
                  "name": "B1-C1-D3-E5",
                  "value": 5,
                  "health": 0.6
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "B1-C1-D4",
              "value": 2,
              "health": 0.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "B1-C2",
          "health": 0.45,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "B1-C2-D1",
              "health": 0.45,
              "value": 12
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "B1-C3",
          "health": 0.5,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "B1-C3-D1",
              "health": 0.5,
              "value": 10
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 selections are **immutable**.

When you do this...

```
nodes.enter()
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d.depth < 3;
    })
    .append('g')
    .merge(nodes)
    //etc...
```

... the `merge` is not changing what `nodes` is, which is just the update selection.

You have to reassign it:

```
nodes = nodes.enter()
    //etc...
```

Here is your code with that change (in a smaller SVG):

```js
const data = {
  "name": "A1",
  "health": 0.521,
  "children": [{
    "name": "B1",
    "health": 0.521,
    "children": [{
        "name": "B1-C1",
        "health": 0.614,
        "children": [{
            "name": "B1-C1-D1",
            "health": 0.666,
            "children": [{
                "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
                "value": 30,
                "health": 0.8
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
                "value": 35,
                "health": 0.5
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D1-E3",
                "value": 20,
                "health": 0.7
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D2",
            "health": 0.45,
            "children": [{
                "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                "value": 10,
                "health": 0.8
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
                "value": 14,
                "health": 0.1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3",
            "health": 0.64,
            "children": [{
                "name": "B1-C1-D3-E1",
                "value": 10,
                "health": 0.8
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D3-E2",
                "value": 14,
                "health": 0.2
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D3-E3",
                "value": 7,
                "health": 0.7
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D3-E4",
                "value": 9,
                "health": 0.9
              },
              {
                "name": "B1-C1-D3-E5",
                "value": 5,
                "health": 0.6
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D4",
            "value": 2,
            "health": 0.7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "B1-C2",
        "health": 0.45,
        "children": [{
          "name": "B1-C2-D1",
          "health": 0.45,
          "value": 12
        }]
      },
      {
        "name": "B1-C3",
        "health": 0.5,
        "children": [{
          "name": "B1-C3-D1",
          "health": 0.5,
          "value": 10
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}

const treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([500, 300])
  .paddingOuter(16);

// update the view
const update = (d) => {
  //console.log(d)

  let rootNode = d3.hierarchy(d)

  console.log(rootNode)

  rootNode
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value;
    });

  treemapLayout(rootNode);


  let nodes = d3.select('svg g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(rootNode.descendants())

  nodes
    .exit().remove()

  nodes = nodes
    .enter()
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d.depth < 3;
    })
    .append('g')
    .merge(nodes)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
    })



  //nodes
  nodes.append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return d.x1 - d.x0;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return d.y1 - d.y0;
    })
    .attr('style', function(d) {
      return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
    })
    .on('click', function(d) {
      console.log(d.data.name);
      update(d);
    })

  nodes
    .append('text')
    .attr('dx', 4)
    .attr('dy', 14)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    })

};

update(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300">
  <g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That definitely fixed the issue with not hitting those code blocks...I will still need to figure out the drill in/drill out.